# android edit text view only 2 lines

Tags: android, textview

in my android app, i would like to set an limit of 2 lines in a edit textview.

i set in my design:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textViewBarcode"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textColor="@color/DefaultGreen"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="@string/HintBarcode"
    android:textColorHint="@color/DefaultGreen"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:height="20dp"
    android:editable="false"
    android:maxlines="2"/>
```

but this doesn't work

it should be possible to make one return in the textview - but no more.
is this possible??

Comment: android:marlines="2" and singleLine="false"

Comment: sry, wrong values. look again. this is how it is

Answer (score 5):

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewBarcode"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" <!-- Multiline input -->
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:editable="false"
        android:maxLines="2" <!-- Maximum Lines -->
        android:lines="2"/>  <!-- Total Lines prior display -->
```

Comment: Good, it worked. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use inputType="textMultiLine" instead of inputType="text"

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewBarcode"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:singleLine="false"

         android:editable="false"
        android:maxlines="2"/>
```

Comment: I tried this before posting and entered a long text string. I saw it wrap before I posted? Can you explain what you mean by "dosen't work".

Comment: the user should only make one return (2 lines), but i can make endless returns (endless lines)

Comment: you could set height for max height or you can limit input length maxlength. I'm not sure there is a way to do specifically what you want short of some coding.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="2"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="25dp"
            android:text="@string/desc"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
```

Somehow `android:maxLines="2"` is not enough  `android:lines="2"` is the answer

```
            android:ellipsize="end" // 3 dots at the end
            android:lines="2" // limits the lines
```

Comment: this one is good answer, worked

Answer (score 0):

Above giving answers are not solved my issue.
Here is the solution

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/etAddress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:hint="Enter Your Address"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="2"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            />
```

Make inputType = textMultiLine and lines as your requirement.
Hope this will solve everyone solution.